# Does loading scripts dynamically block the rendering?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm trying to load bootstrap.min.js file.
I have two options.
The first one is to load it from a remote server:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
 </head>
 <body>
  ...
 </body>
</html>
```

The second one is to load it from my server:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
 </head>
 <body>
  ...
 </body>
</html>
```

In the first case the script will load asynchronously which means the rendering of my page won't be blocked.
In the second case the script will block the rendering of my page. Am I correct?

How will blootstrap.min.js be loaded (async or sync) if I try to do this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
   var bootstrap = document.createElement('script');
    bootstrap.src = "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js";
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(bootstrap);
  </script>
  ...
 </body>
</html>
```

And this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
   var bootstrap = document.createElement('script');
    bootstrap.src = "js/bootstrap.min.js";
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(bootstrap);
  </script>
  ...
 </body>
</html>
```

I have a hunch that in both cases the rendering won't be blocked. What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: It will be asynchronous...

Comment: try using async attribute to script
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you put the source-loading code at the end of your `<body>` tag, the rendering won't be blocked, even though the new `script` tags are appended to the head. That's because most of the rendering is already done when you get to that part.

[In newer browsers](https://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/), you can add an `async` attribute to the script tag, which will not block rendering. So I suspect loading the file asynchronously via JS will not block rendering either, even if you do it near the top of the file.

Comment: how can I append something and still block. ? Thanks